# Oracle 10g express edition import

Tags: oracle, import

How can i import a DMP file into my oracle 10g expression edition database?

I tried with `imp` but its showing an error:

```
IMP-00010: not a valid export file, header failed verification
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the exp was done with a version of 10g that is lower or equal to the version of the oracle 10xe.   If it was done with expdp instead of exp, you will not be able to import it using imp.   You can not import a dump file into an older db an exp that was done with the exp of a newer version.   I would suggest you find out what the exact version of the exp tool used and if it was exp vs expdp.   If necessary use the exp tool from the 10xe and exp what your need remotely from the 10g enterprise db.  Then you be ensure you can imp it.

Answer (score 1):

I fear that there is no easy way to import this DMP file with that error message. Are you sure that the DMP file was exported with `exp` and that nobody has tampered with it aftwerwards. Maybe this is a shot in the dark but possibly you have transfered the DMP file with FTP and forgotten to turn on `binary mode`.

[Oracle Utlities Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/exp_imp.htm#i1013164) states that *The Import utility cannot read export dump files created by the Export utility of a later maintenance release or version. For example, a release 9.2 export dump file cannot be imported by a release 9.0.1 Import utility.*

Now, I am not sure if *oracle 10g enterprise edition* is considered a later maintenance release compared to *oracle 10g express*. Anyway, I'd try to use the same exp and imp version, propably the one of oracle 10g express.

Comment: exp was done from other system which has oracle 10g enterprise edition and was transfered to mine via a pendrive. mine is oracle 10g express edition

Comment: importing a DMP file should alway be possible, if the versions of the export tool (exp) and the import tool (imp) match. I can only think of a file corruption as the reason for the failure.